# How to copy files from directory to another location (Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel, storage, lumen

I want to copy my directory from one place to another

Try to use facade Storage

```
Storage::disk('local')->copy('path/from/', 'path/to/');
```

Error:

```
copy(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory
```

I tried to find answer in the Internet, but didn't find for Laravel 8

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: The copy method may be used to copy an existing file to a new location on the disk [doc link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files), so first argument should be a path to the file `Storage::copy('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');`

Comment: Ok, but how can I copy directory with files to another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через `Storage`, наверное, как-то так:

```
$files = Storage::disk('local')->allFiles('path/from/');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $newPath = str_replace('path/from/', 'path/to/', $file);
    Storage::disk('local')->copy($file, $newPath);
}
```

Ещё у `File` есть метод `copyDirectory()`, но он работает только через полные пути.

```
\File::copyDirectory(storage_path('app/path/from'), storage_path('app/path/to'));
```

Comment: Значит нету более лаконичного метода? И что за фасад использует File?

Comment: File и есть фасад, предоставляет Illuminate/Filesystem по идее.